# How to add two foreign keys and add values in child table with reference of parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables in my database USERS, QUESTION, and ANSWER. I want QUESTION table to interact with USERS and ANSWER table and ANSWER table to USER and QUESTION table. So far I have related QUESTION table with USERS table using foreign key and ANSWER table with QUESTION table.
When I am trying to add second foreign key in ANSWER table in mysql I am getting an error
a) Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'userid'
Even if I am trying to add using query it still giving me an error.

Can I add values in QUESTION table in reference with USERS table with help of foreign key? for e.g. i have user in USERS table with userid 1 i want to add values in QUESTION table where quesid will be 1 and also userid also be 1. Till now I have tried this query

```
INSERT INTO users_ques 
    SELECT "What is JAVA","Please Share the details" FROM users WHERE quesid = 1;
```

Below are my tables and their script

USERS TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

QUESTION TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `users_ques` (
  `quesid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ques` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ques_desc` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`quesid`),
  CONSTRAINT `userid` FOREIGN KEY (`quesid`) REFERENCES `users` (`userid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

ANSWER TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `users_ans` (
  `ansid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ans` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ansid`),
  CONSTRAINT `quesid` FOREIGN KEY (`ansid`) REFERENCES `users_ques` (`quesid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Do users pick an answer from the answer table (like multiple choice) or do they give a free text answer that is inserted into the answer table?

Comment: Does the user is one who answers or creates the question?

Comment: When doing inserts, please always list the column names. Otherwise later on when you need to make changes to your table, things will break.

Comment: @stickybit hey user can pick any question from database and can answer them.

Comment: @Akina hey So a user can pick any question from database and can answer them. for ex. In users table there is one user with userid = 1 and in question table there is question with questionid = 1 which is asked by userid = 2 or anyone. So userid 1 can answer that question and in answer table  that should get updated with answerid =1 with reference of userid 1.

Comment: One user may create a question. Another user may answer the question. Does third user can answer this question too?

Comment: @Akina yes any user can answer any question except his own asked question. It will just increase the count of answer for the same question.

Comment: I.e. you have classic 1:M relation for question-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommended structure (use as a base, adjust to real data):

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, -- unique index
  username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  password VARBINARY(255) NOT NULL,                -- password hash, binary
  firstname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  address VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  phone BIGINT DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE question (
  question_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  -- unique index
  question_text TEXT NOT NULL,        
  user_id INT NOT NULL,                                 -- id of the user who have asked
  CONSTRAINT user_to_question FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE answer (
  answer_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  -- unique index
  answer_text TEXT NOT NULL,
  question_id INT NOT NULL,                           -- what question it answers on
  user_id INT NOT NULL,                               -- id of the user who have answered
  CONSTRAINT user_to_answer FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id),
  CONSTRAINT question_to_answer FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question (question_id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

---

In this scheme I do not show the restriction that the user cannot answer his own question. I consider such a restriction to be meaningless. But if you need in it nevertheless then you may add it by creating 2 triggers (BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE) on `answer` table.

Comment: hi @Akina thanks for the solution it worked. Special thanks for the password thing in user table.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is exactly as it says, you are trying to add another constraint with the symbol `userid` but you already have one with that name on the `users_ques` table.

As per [13.1.20.5 FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> The CONSTRAINT symbol value, if defined, must be unique in the
> database. A duplicate symbol results in an error similar to: ERROR
> 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test.fk1' (errno: 121).

So, you either need to assign a database unique name to your constraint or allow the server to assign one for you. If you want to explicitly name them use expressive names that are unlikely to collide. Something like `FK_<table_name>_<column_name>`.

Also, probably a copy and paste error, but your `users_ans` looks completely wrong. `ansid` appears to be typical surrogate key but is then used as the foreign key to `users_ques`.`quesid` in your constraint. It looks like you are missing `userid` and `quesid`. There's a similar issue with your constraint and columns on `users_ques`

```sql
/* Allowing the server to create the indices and auto-name the constraints */
CREATE TABLE `users_ans` (
    `ansid` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `quesid` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `userid` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `ans` varchar(200) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`ansid`),

    FOREIGN KEY (`quesid`)
      REFERENCES `users_ques` (`quesid`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`userid`)
      REFERENCES `users` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

/* Explicitly naming indices and constraints */
CREATE TABLE `users_ans` (
    `ansid` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `quesid` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `userid` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `ans` varchar(200) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`ansid`),
    INDEX `idx_users_ans_quesid` (quesid),
    INDEX `idx_users_ans_userid` (userid),

    CONSTRAINT `FK_users_ans_quesid`
      FOREIGN KEY `idx_users_ans_quesid` (`quesid`)
      REFERENCES `users_ques` (`quesid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_users_ans_userid`
      FOREIGN KEY `idx_users_ans_userid` (`userid`)
      REFERENCES `users` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

If users can only have one answer per question then you can drop the current surrogate key in favour of the natural key on (quesid, userid) -

```sql
/* This option only applies if a user can only answer a question once */
CREATE TABLE `users_ans` (
    `quesid` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `userid` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `ans` varchar(200) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`quesid`, `userid`),
    INDEX `idx_inv_primary` (`userid`, `quesid`), -- probably needed for joins in both directions and will be used by `FK_users_ans_userid`

    CONSTRAINT `FK_users_ans_quesid`
      FOREIGN KEY (`quesid`)
      REFERENCES `users_ques` (`quesid`)
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_users_ans_userid`
      FOREIGN KEY (`userid`)
      REFERENCES `users` (`userid`)
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

As show in this last example, I prefer to include the referential actions, even when using the default, as it makes the intent clear.

Here's a little [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=662d1ad65838ad85264505a7c597bf8d)

Your QUESTION table seems to be inappropriately named. As per your title above the create table statement, `questions` would appear to be the obvious name for the table.

I do not understand your second question, nor why you would want to add the `userid` to the "QUESTION TABLE".  If you would like more help please add more detail to your question to clarify the issues.

Comment: hi, so the second solution worked for me. So I did same for the question table also it worked absolutely fine. But now i have to change everything in my spring model and dao file too

Comment: Please accept if it helped you understand your issue. Also, bear in mind suggestions relating to table and column names. Avoid unnecessary abbreviation, as it just adds confusion.